# What does it mean when a file appears red on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am unsure why my file is appearing in red font.
Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This is a feature fix released back in January 2018.
Here is the link for explaination - [Error Indicators in the Exploer](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_error-indicators-in-the-explorer)

It shows you which files have error:

> the number of errors/warnings is shown in the decoration. The setting
>   `problems.decorations.enabled` allows you to enable/disable the
>   error/warning decorations.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is to show you that there is an error in the file. More information on this can be found here:
[VSCode Issues 782](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/782)

As you can see here, the file appears red when something in the file is an error.

[image]

This type of information is considered to be `file-decorations`. More information on that [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/labels/file-decorations)