# What is this marked number next to the file name in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know the meaning of **M** as "modified" on the right side of the file name.

But what is that **number 4** next to the M ?

Is there a name for these marks?
Any docs of this will helpful!

[image: example image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean when a file appears red on Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223769/what-does-it-mean-when-a-file-appears-red-on-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @underscore_d It's a little different case I think, because it does not appearing red color when out of focused

Comment: I think it should. Maybe your theme is interfering with the colours somehow?

Comment: @underscore_d yes Maybe, this color theme makes it confusing

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That is the number of linting errors and warnings currently in the file.

To see the actual errors and their details, open the [Problems panel](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_basic-layout), which by default is at the bottom part of the editor. (If it's not shown, open it by going to the menu **View** > **Problems**).

Comment: Yes, probably. OP should check their "problems" tab and will probably see a corresponding set of errors or warnings.

Comment: Thanks , I think this answer is exact, I just counted error(ts error) and it was 4 of them

Comment: What's the name of this element? I know the 'M' is a git decoration. Is the number a lint decoration?

Answer (score 13):

As @Goofballtech mentioned, this is the number of errors & warnings associated with a given file. You can turn this off by setting `problems.decorations.enabled` to false in your VSCode `settings.json`.

You can find more information here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_error-indicators-in-the-explorer