# Error sign with javascript code after upgrading to 1.65.0

Tags: visual-studio-code

After upgrading to version 1.65.0, the file explorer started to show strange sign of `2,M` & `1,U` by some file name. But there is no explanation about what's wrong with the JS code. How to fix the problem?

[image]

Comment: The `2, M` are two separate indicators. The `2` means 2 errors, which you can see in the Problems tab. The `M` is a version control indicator (most likely git) that says the file has been modified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this marked number next to the file name in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327644/what-is-this-marked-number-next-to-the-file-name-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the U and M file markers in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48304195/2745495)

Comment: Is the error related to code version update? There was no code change.

Comment: It's impossible to say with just the filename and the number "2". As mentioned in one of the links, check the Problems panel to see what errors you now get, _and research about that instead_. Focusing on the VS Code version is unhelpful. Maybe the internal linter for JS got an update and is now showing errors that were not previously reported.